# Truncate letters from the end in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have col A in the table and I want to truncate all the letters after last digit in the values of col A and create col B.

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| A1234ABC | A1234 |
| B1234AB | B1234 |

How can I convert col A to col B in postgres.(Alphabet length at the end is not sure it can be 3 or 2.)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` with a regex

```
select substring(col_a from '^.*[0-9]+')
from the_table
```

It extracts everything from the start up until at least one or more digits. It will "fail" for input values that have no digits all. e.g. `'ABCD'` as the input will result in an empty string.